# VPN disconnects immediately

Tags: vpn, openvpn

My android phone connect to VPN then immediately disconnects, I tried most of VPNs on Google Play Store but it's not working.

OpenVPN connects barely and disconnects in less than 1 minute, my network is good and I can connect VPN on my laptop with my network.

```
01:06:43.695 -- EVENT: CONNECTED info='ir443391@nl.ovadd.com:800 (134.19.177.20) via /UDPv4 on tun/10.11.3.202/ gw=[10.11.3.201/]' trans=TO_CONNECTED 
01:08:09.304 -- EVENT: DISCONNECTED trans=TO_DISCONNECTED 01:08:09.321 -- EVENT: CORE_THREAD_INACTIVE 
01:08:09.322 -- Tunnel bytes per CPU second: 0 
01:08:09.323 -- ----- OpenVPN Stop ----- –
```

Comment: Have you checked the OpenVPN log file (there should be an option in the app to view it)?

Answer (score 0):

Is your Android phone killing apps from the background? Check for background activity manage, battery optimizer or a similar option in your device settings and disable it for your VPN app.

Comment: I disabled Battey optimizer for all VPN apps